# Cassandra: Unable to coerce '2016-04-06 13:06:11.534000' to a formatted date (long)

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to UPDATE an existing item in my cassandra DB using cqlsh:

```
$ > UPDATE allEvents SET "isLastEvent" = True WHERE "websiteId" = 'sd-8231'
AND "purchaser" = False
AND "currentTime" = '2016-04-06 13:06:11.534000';
```

And I got this:

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '2016-04-06 13:06:11.534000' to a formatted date (long)"

In case it can help:

```
$ > show version
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.2 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
```

Comment: Do you need the extra precision? Cassandra's timestamp type will only support milliseconds. If you need a higher precision you could use the timeuuid type (UUIDv1) which is accurate to 100 nanosecond intervals.

Answer (score 29):

That's because Cassandra timestamp types only support milliseconds.  Your `currentTime` has too much precision.  Trim off the last three zeros, and that should work:

```
UPDATE allEvents SET "isLastEvent" = True 
WHERE "websiteId" = 'sd-8231'
      AND "purchaser" = False 
      AND "currentTime" = '2016-04-06 13:06:11.534';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but why this doesn't matter when I inserted it?

Comment: @farhawa I am guessing that whatever client you're using to insert data into Cassandra is treating insert differently than updates and silently removing the extra precision.

Answer (score 4):

There is a reason for the "unable to coerce '2016-04-06 13:06:11.534000' to a  formatted date (long)" error, although, the timestamp column actually stores milliseconds in all versions, there seem to be some differences in how you can query based on the version:

Cassandra <=2.1 does not seem to support milliseconds in query: yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html

Whereas >=3.0 supports it: yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ffffffZ
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html

I verified being able to select/insert in a newer cluster but not in old cluster using my IDE connected on 9160 Thrift port, have not yet tried on cqlsh:

```
INSERT INTO "sp.status"("ams", "load_start_time")
    VALUES('RRG', '2018-05-01T16:57:18.123+0200')
;

-- same with select, works on new cluster but not old
SELECT * FROM sp.status WHERE ams = 'RRG' AND load_start_time='2018-05-01T16:57:18.123+0200'
;
```

The driver seems to be able to map a java date and store milliseconds in both old and new cluster though.

> =Cassandra 2.1 cqlsh uses native binary protocol (9042), previous versions use thrift (9160) although this should not change.